# Embedded Jetty IllegalStateException: Committed

Tags: java, jersey, embedded-jetty

I am using jetty embedded to jersey. My standalone jetty works well but it starts to idle after a time later. I gives response within 2 ms. however it starts to give respone 8000 ms. and idles. I profiled it but couldn't find anything. I get that error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1056)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:509)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1048)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:601)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:664)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

I tired to change threadpool settings and did that:

```
 server.setThreadPool(new ExecutorThreadPool(64,256,10));
```

**PS 1:** https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cometd-users/5yhMwIlRVbg/fL7V3mwWKyoJ here says that executer is not good as jetty's thread pool but I am not sure.

I use: *7.4.5.v20110725* of jetty-servlet and jetty-security.

**PS 2:** I found that: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/8.0.0.M0/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Response.java#1103

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas about problem?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33439827/179850

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably too late, but I've just bumped into this myself, using Jetty 8.x embedded under JPOS.
Wrote a test handler and quickly configured it under the HandlerCollection:
HandlerCollection
...ContextHandler
...RequestLogHandler
...**FunkyHandler**
In other words, it was the last to be executed. Which barfed up this:
java.lang.**IllegalStateException**: STREAM     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.getWriter(Response.java:699)
     at com.acs.test.jetty.FunkyHandler.handle(FunkyHandler.java:26)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)

Tried it with OutputStream, which gave me the Committed state error, same as OP.
So, after reading somewhere here that these handlers are invoked in the order they're configure, the fix was easy {this probably works also when you set up the handlers in code}:
HandlerCollection
...**FunkyHandler**
...ContextHandler
...RequestLogHandler

As I haven't bothered to read the Jetty docs, I'm pretty sure this is mentioned somewhere, but here it is. Hope it helps somebody.