# jetty webSocket : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

Tags: servlets, jetty

I am using Jetty Websockets in my Web Application .

When i am trying to redirect to a logoff jsp , i am getting this error

```
oejs.ServletHandler:/test
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1069)
        at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(ServletResponseWrapper.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.gzip.GzipResponseWrapper.resetBuffer(GzipResponseWrapper.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:98)
```

This is the way i am redirecting

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("logoff.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

This error is not reproduceble , but could you please tell me when it may occur??

Comment: what do you mean by _"This error is not reproduceble"_ ? Is it happening sporadically?

Comment: Consider accepting my response if it was helpful.

Answer (score 17):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed

I thought I'd provide a more general explanation of what the exception means.  First off, Jetty should be ashamed by the exception message.  It provides little to no help to the developer unless they already know what it actually means.  The exception should be something like:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response headers have already been sent.  Are you trying to return a result after sending content?

Typically this exception happens when you go and call:

```
 resp.getOutputStream();  // or getWriter()
```

and then later try to do a redirect or something:

```
 resp.sendRedirect("/someOtherUrl");
 // or
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/someOtherUrl");
```

Once you get the `OutputStream` or `Writer` so you can write body bytes to the client, Jetty has to commit the response and send the HTTP `200` and associated headers, so it can start returning the body bytes.  Once that happens, you then can't do a redirect nor make any other changes to the status code or headers.

The proper thing to do, once you return body bytes, is to return `null` from the handler instead of a `ModelAndView(...)` or just change the handler to return `void`.

Answer (score 2):

You also get this exception when you call the super method in your own method implementation.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    super.doPost(req, resp); // <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    resp.sendRedirect("/someOtherUrl");
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is true unless the super class actually committing the response.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because your response has already processed a redirect request, you are trying to modify a committed response.

There are two general ways to solve this:

1. find out where the first redirect is and try to modify the logic to prevent the "two redirect" scenario from happening.
2. put a "return" after each of your redirect (personally I recommend this solution).

Answer (score 1):

The reason on my side is using jetty with wrong url:
right: `http://localhost:8080`
wrong: `http://localhost:8080/test`

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are running `javax.servlet.Filter` on Jetty server, and you face the same exception. The issue here can be described exactly as Gray's description (Thanks Gray). Typically this exception happens when you go and call:

```
resp.getOutputStream();  // or getWriter()
```

then

```
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

If you called `resp.getOutputStream();`, make sure you are not using `chain.doFilter(request, response);` on the same request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some repository in my `@Service` and I declared it as `RepositoryFoo repositoryFoo;`, in the beginning of my class

I forgot to add `@Autowired` or even make it `private`, so it compiled fine and then when running I had this `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed` ... I wasted some time before figuring out the reason !